# Update customer Password in Magento

Tags: android, magento

I am trying to update customer password but its not updating,other customer related information is updating like as username and email. I am getting true in the response after updating the password. below is the code.

```
env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
env.dotNet = false;
env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerEntityToCreate");
customerEntity.addProperty("email",email);
customerEntity.addProperty("customer_id",customerId);
customerEntity.addProperty("firstname",firstName);
customerEntity.addProperty("lastname",lastName);
customerEntity.addProperty("password",password);
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerUpdate");
request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
request.addProperty("customerId", customerId);
request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);

env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
(new MarshalHashtable()).register(env);
try {
    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
} catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    result = env.getResponse();
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (SoapFault e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this already then I study about this, As according to my knowledge its unable to set password for the customer from API. Because in magento they are using a filter inside the customer create methode like this `$data = $validator->filter($data);`   . So here the password which we sent is filtered. To avoid this I get the password before filter and set it after the filter as shown below. I am using REST Api I think you have the same problem in your SOAP Api, just change the SOAP Api `customer create method/customer update method` in magento like this, it may solve your problem.

```
protected function _create(array $data)
    {
        $password = $data['password'];
        $validator = Mage::getResourceModel('api2/validator_eav', array('resource' => $this));
        $data = $validator->filter($data);
        $data['password'] = $password;
        if (!$validator->isValidData($data))
        {
            foreach ($validator->getErrors() as $error)
            {
                $this->_error($error, Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_DATA_PRE_VALIDATION_ERROR);
        }

        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setData($data);

        try
        {
            $customer->setPassword($data['password']);      //added
            $customer->setWebsiteId(1)->save(); 

        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_error($e->getMessage(), Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remees: Thanks for your response but actually i am not getting your  thoughts, also I am not familiar with PHP code.what changes we need to do in customer create and update methods?

Comment: The problem is not in your code you posted, the problem is in server side. Do you know how to code magento? if not ask help for someone who is dealing with magento there.